AnimatePresence Is not yielding to the CSS overflow hidden
I'm trying to build a Text Slider that slides text indefinitely from top to bottom, I've tried Wait, It is slow, and sync, which had some layout issues where the text(initial) goes beyond where it's supposed to be and pops back up. they're not working right for this situation, Then i used poplayout, it worked- i thought.
 <div>
        <h1 className='SliderSpan'>
          <AnimatePresence mode='popLayout' initial={false}>
        <motion.div
        initial={{ transform: 'translateY(-100px)', opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: 1 }}
        exit={{ transform: 'translateY(100px)', opacity: 0 }}
        transition={{
          duration: 0.5
        }}
        key={currentIndex}
      >
        {ArrayofspanStrings[currentIndex]}
      </motion.div>
      </AnimatePresence>
        </h1>

.SliderSpan {
    height: 100px;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden ;
    gap: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family:  'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    
    div{
      background-clip: text;
      background-color: salmon;
      color: transparent;
    }
    
    font-size: 25px;
  }

When the motion.div element exit the parent div that has The overflow: hidden;
It floats down, doesn't slide to the abyss, it just pops when it reaches the exit destination. Is there any explanation for this? The documentation is dull.
I tried removing the overflow, nothing changed. The "Wait" property is slow but almost Achieves what i want.
